# copy attribute from session to request scope

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to copy int[] named idNumbers from session scope to request scope.
The code below doesnt work as I get null pointer exception in my controller whenever trying to retrieve attribute from request scope. I am feeling I am not either understanding the scopes or I either set the property in wrong way.

the jsp code

```
<c:if test="${sessionScope.idNumbers!=null}"> // this line is OK and session scope contains the idNumbers(checked)
  <% request.setAttribute("activityId", session.getAttribute("idNumbers")); %>
  <c:set var="activityId" scope="request" value="${sessionScope.idNumbers}"/>
  <form class="spanFormat" method="post" action="/blablabla">
    <p>
      <input value="Attach" type="submit" style="color: green;" />
      <input name="programId" style="display: none;" value="${blabla.programId}" />
    </p>
  </form>
</c:if>
```

the controller code, here I tried different approaches, but essentially the result tells that such parameter doesn't exist in request scope when it should.

the first two give nulls(empty) and then null pointer exception:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/program/set", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setActivitiesForProgram(@RequestParam("activityId") int[] activitiesNumbers,
        Model model, HttpSession hs, HttpServletRequest hr)
        throws ServletRequestBindingException {
    String activityNumber1 = (String) hr.getParameter("activityId");
    logger.info(activityNumber1);

    String activityNumber = (String) hr.getAttribute("activityId");
    logger.info(activityNumber);

    String[] activitiesNumbersss = (String[])    hr.getAttribute("activityId");
    logger.info(activitiesNumbersss[0]);

    String[] activitiesNumberss = hr.getParameterValues("activityId");
    logger.info(activitiesNumberss[0]);

    return "someView";
 }
```

Comment: Why would you want to copy something available in a wider scope to a narrower scope?

Comment: I forgot to include @RequestParam("activityId") int[] activitiesNumbers, for controller. I want to reuse this method(as several pages are served by this) without adding extra code to the method itself. If I have @RequestParam annotation the parameter should be provided as mandatory parameter. If I don't provide it then I will get BAD Http Request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the request attribute in the *current* request--not the *new* one made on form submission.

Use a hidden form field filled with the session value, or just pull it from the session directly--I don't see a compelling reason to copy it somewhere *else* if you already have it.

Comment: You are thousand times correct, I just realized that. I have done that because I wanted to reuse controller method(as it used by several pages). And originally it had @RequestParam("activityId") int[] activitiesNumbers,   as you can see if I don't provide activityId from request I will get returned BAD REQUEST 400 or 500 http error.